# handling multi clients in node.js api

Tags: javascript, node.js

Couldn't find an answer, so I'm asking here -

I'm writing an API in node.js (6.2.0) and I have a problem when I'm serving to multiple clients.

The code is -

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();

const FileRetriever = require('./FileRetriever');


function doSomething(uid, callback) {
    let finalCount = 0;
    let cb = null;

    FileRetriever.foo(uid, function (err, data) {
        finalCount = data.length;

        cb = callback(finalCount);

        data.forEach(function(obj, i) {
            doSomething2(obj, cb);
        });
    })
}

function doSomething2(_obj, cb) {
    let fn = null;

    FileRetriever.bar(_obj, function(err, data){
        cb(null, data);       
    })

}

router.route('/foo').get(function (req, res) {
    let uid = req.query.uid;

    function callback(_finalCount) {
        let counter    = 1;
        let finalCount = _finalCount;
        let output     = [];

        return function(err, data) {
            output.push(data);

            if (output.length === (finalCount -1)) {
                res.send(output);
            }
        }
    }

    doSomething(uid, callback);
});
```

Obviously it's a bit more complicated than that, but this is the simplified version.

Please help me understand what am I missing - 
This is what I have in mind on how it should work -

A user goes to `/foo` with a parameter uid.
He gets to this route and `doSomething` is invoked for this user.
In `doSomething`, I first get initial data that I invoke `callback` with that returns a function of its own which will be now known as `cb`.

When `cb` is passed to `doSomething2` and get invoked there, it's still under the same stack, under the same user.

I ran a couple of tests, with one user that should return an output with the length of 6 and another with the length of 100.

When I run this code once per user, it all works fine, but if the route gets called at the same time by the two users, the lengths are not [6,100] (but they are always the same).

What am I doing wrong? 
It should work...

Hope that I was clear, thanks.

Comment: you should create a separate file that exports the functions which you want to use and require it just like you required express. Then you need to call these functions within your route.get function.
I believe what you are experiencing right now is that the functions are set globaly and one user overwrites the value of the other users function